# Stripe API Recurring Payment: 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Dotenv\Dotenv"'

Tags: php, composer-php, stripe-payments

I'm a total newbie and I'm merely piecing tutorials and use cases together to speed up my understanding of this new field, so apologies for not knowing what's going on.

Anyway, here's the situation: I'm using xampp as a test server to create a database driven website that includes a login page, a search page, and a profile page where you can subscribe to recurring packages using Stripe's API.

Following Stripe's instructions here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout, I copied all the code from [Github](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-single-subscription/blob/master/server/php-slim/index.php) to take care of step 4 and refreshed the index page, just to kind of see if there's something going on. I ended up getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Dotenv\Dotenv" not found in C:\xampp\root\index.php:15
```

I downloaded composer using the windows installer, and right after, I verified by typing in 'composer' in the command terminal to see if it's working. At this point, I'm not sure what's going on. In the vendor directory, symfony, stripe and composer have their own folders.

Can someone help?

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php";
include "header.php";   //just some script and style sources, as well as the upper half of the html body tag
require_once("stripe-php/init.php");


use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Stripe\Stripe;

require 'C:/Users/USER/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If your file is stored at `C:\xampp\root\ `, why do you try to require the autoloader from `C:/Users/USER/vendor`?

Comment: Did you follow [the instructions to install the Stripe PHP sample code](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-single-subscription/tree/master/server/php-slim)?  I'm specifically wondering if you downloaded all the files there and ran `composer install` or only downloaded the code in `index.php`?

Comment: @NicoHaase, not much in terms of debugging since I don't totally understand the problem. I just checked if the stripe client is installed. I'm not sure why the autoloader is necessary, I really couldn't question it yet. The code from github is a direct "Click to view full sample code" on Stripe's website, so I just assumed it would work.

Comment: @JustinMichael, I pretty much just copied the code from the sample index.php to my own file. I downloaded composer and installed stripe. I'm guessing that's not enough, lol. I got so overwhelmed and so confused by everything I saw there, but now that you've sort of pointed it out, I do notice all the other files there that seems necessary that I didn't download.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the `index.php` code won't work on its own, it's designed to work with the rest of the sample code in that repo.  You might want to use [a simpler example with fewer dependencies](https://github.com/VioletPixel/stripe-php-samples/blob/main/samples/checkout-one-time-payment.php) instead (that's for one-time purchases, but it's easy enough to modify for subscriptions by changing some properties).

Comment: Yea, I figured I was way in over my head with this one. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I'll try that one instead.

Comment: A little late: I encountered the "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Dotenv\Dotenv" not found ..." The issue, described at https://dev.to/eriesgo/dotenv-and-relative-paths-fp2 , was to edit the path in the file:line indicated in the error. In my case, in `.dotenv.php` I needed to change the relative path `require_once('vendor/autoload.php');` to the full path (obfuscated here) `require_once('/home/me/.../vendor/autoload.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing that error is that you only copied the `index.php` code, which is not designed to work in isolation.  That code has dependencies, one of which being `Dotenv`, that needs to be installed using Composer.

In order to get that sample code working you need to download all the code and follow [the instructions noted in the `php-slim` folder](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-single-subscription/tree/master/server/php-slim):

1. Run `composer install` to install the dependencies
2. Start the test PHP server locally: `php -S localhost:4242 index.php`
3. Open http://localhost:4242 in your browser

See also [the instructions at the top-level of that repo](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-single-subscription).

Comment: Yep. Sorry for missing something so obvious like that. It just got so overwhelming. I can understand PHP and how data get passed between the server and the client, the url and all that stuff, but PHP libraries and that composer stuff are totally new so my critical thinking just kind of shut down.

Either way, I appreciate you guys spending time to understand my problem and to provide a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do it so:

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(**DIR**);
$dotenv->load();